# Django: Class-based views, URL and template_name

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I am trying to use something like `polls:detail`in a class-based view, such as this:

```
class QuestionDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'polls:result'
```

However, I get a `TemplateDoesNotExist at /polls/2/result
polls:result` error...

The urls.py is:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from polls.views import IndexView, DetailView, ResultsView

from . import views


app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', IndexView.as_view(), name='index'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$', DetailView.as_view(), name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/result$', ResultsView.as_view(), name='result'),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/vote$', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

I guess the main question is, how do I use the names of URLs in class-based views, instead of explicitly providing the template name, such as `polls/question_results.html`?

Is there anything other than `template_name`?

I was reading that it's a good practice to use names in URLS so in case the URL itself changes, the rest of the code still works, so that's what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Url name and template names are very different things. `template_name` is a path to the `.html` file. Url name you can use to reverse url from name, with `django.urls.reverse` function

Comment: If you put this as an answer, I will mark it the correct one, as this one helped my the most.

Comment: answer added! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Url name and template name are very absolutely things.

`template_name` is a path to the `.html` file.

Url's `name` parameter you can use to reverse url from name using  `django.urls.reverse`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the name of URL like this:
django.urls.reverse('polls:detail', args=[object.id])

And you have to change the template_name settings as well and to create a template detail.html in your current template folder.

template_name = 'polls/detail.html'